# trouble loading ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble loading ggplot2 using R version 2.12.1, as shown below.  The only help I can find suggests loading "proto".  I tried that and it didn't fix my problem.  Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thanks,

peter l

```
> install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)
trying URL 'http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/macosx/leopard/contrib/2.12/ggplot2_0.8.9.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2481399 bytes (2.4 Mb)
opened URL
=================================================
downloaded 2.4 Mb


The downloaded packages are in
    /var/folders/XF/XF0tU7gdGTeF4Th7KhKYDk+++TI/-Tmp-//RtmpFMnqLB/downloaded_packages
> library(ggplot2)
Error in assign(names[i], dots[[i]], env = envir) : 
  invalid first argument
Error : unable to load R code in package 'ggplot2'
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'ggplot2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, have you omitted some lines there, before the `The downloaded packages are in....`? I get:

```
> install.packages('ggplot2', dep = TRUE)
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/gavin/R/libs’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.uk.r-project.org/src/contrib/ggplot2_0.8.9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2074749 bytes (2.0 Mb)
o    pened URL
==================================================
downloaded 2.0 Mb

* installing *source* package ‘ggplot2’ ...
** R
** data
**  moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices ...
** testing if installed package can be loaded

* DONE (ggplot2)

The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpfDSoM8/downloaded_packages’
> require(ggplot2)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: reshape
Loading required package: plyr

Attaching package: 'reshape'

The following object(s) are masked from 'package:plyr':

    round_any

Loading required package: grid
Loading required package: proto
```

Do you also see the `* Done (ggplot2)` message for example? If not, the installation likely failed for some reason and we need more details in order to help.

The above was on

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.1 Patched (2011-02-06 r54249)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.utf8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=C             LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.utf8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.utf8       LC_NAME=C                
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[7] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_0.8.9 proto_0.3-8   reshape_0.8.4 plyr_1.4     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.12.1
```

Comment: I know this isn't a proper Answer, but the comment box was not suitable to show the output expected, and providing it allowed the OP to see what is expected rather than posting their output and waiting for further input. I will delete this answer as the thread develops.

Comment: Hi Gavin-Thanks for the reply.  No, I did not leave anything out of my posting- it is the complete message.  And no, I did not see the * Done (ggplot2) message.  I am including my sesionInfo below.  Thanks.

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 2.12.1 (2010-12-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] proto_0.3-8   reshape_0.8.4 plyr_1.4     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tcltk_2.12.2 tools_2.12.2
>

Comment: @Peter OK, that to me suggests that the installation failed somewhere as proto and reshape seem to have been loaded OK. As you are on a Mac, you might try the r-sig-mac mailing list for assistance.

Comment: Thanks, Gavin.  One thing to point out is that the installation problem is specific to ggplot2, as I am able to install other packages.

Comment: @Peter Point taken, but as the package seems to build on CRAN's Mac machines this sounds like a local issue and you might need to seek expert advice from the R-sig-mac list.